# Data in the table does not update unless you pull to refresh. Swift ios

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, parse-platform, xcode6

The data table in my code does not update unless you pull to refresh. I need the tableview to update instantly when the view loads. I am stuck with this and also I need the data to update on the whenever I change the selection on the segmented controller without me having to always pull to refresh after choosing the specific segment to get the new data. The following is my tableViewController code:

```
class TableViewController: PFQueryTableViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {    
@IBOutlet weak var controller: UISegmentedControl!
var yaks = ["a","b","c", "d", "e"]
var comments: [String]?
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
var currLocation : CLLocationCoordinate2D?

override init!(style: UITableViewStyle, className: String!)
{
    super.init(style: style, className: className)
} 
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    self.parseClassName = "Yak"
    self.textKey = "text"
    self.pullToRefreshEnabled = true
    self.objectsPerPage = 200
    self.paginationEnabled = false
}
private func alert(message : String) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Ooops !!", message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil)
    let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil)
    let settings = UIAlertAction(title: "Settings", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) { (action) -> Void in
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)!)
        return
    }
    alert.addAction(settings)
    alert.addAction(action)
    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didFailWithError error: NSError!) {
    alert("Ooops we are not able to get your location !!")
}



func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {
    locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    if(locations.count > 0){
        let location = locations[0] as CLLocation
        println(location.coordinate)
        currLocation = location.coordinate
    } else {
        alert("Ooops we are not able to get your location !!")
    }
}


override func objectAtIndexPath(indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> PFObject! {
    var obj : PFObject? = nil
    if(indexPath.row < self.objects.count){
        obj = self.objects[indexPath.row] as PFObject
    }

    if(obj?.objectForKey("comments") != nil) {
        comments = obj?.objectForKey("comments") as [String]
    }


    return obj
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 96
    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = 1000
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    let queryLoc = currLocation


     }


   override func queryForTable() -> PFQuery! {
    let query = PFQuery(className: "posts")
    if let queryLoc = currLocation 
    {    
          if controller.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
        query.whereKey("location", nearGeoPoint: PFGeoPoint(latitude: queryLoc.latitude, longitude: queryLoc.longitude), withinMiles: 4)
        query.limit = 200;
            query.orderByDescending("createdAt")
     }

    if controller.selectedSegmentIndex == 1
    {
    query.whereKey("location", nearGeoPoint: PFGeoPoint(latitude:           queryLoc.latitude, longitude: queryLoc.longitude), withinMiles: 4)
            query.limit = 200;
            query.orderByDescending("commentsNo")

        }


        }
         else {
        if controller.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {


        query.whereKey("location", nearGeoPoint: PFGeoPoint(latitude: 37.411822, longitude: -121.941125), withinMiles: 10)
        query.limit = 200;
            query.orderByDescending("createdAt")
          }

         if controller.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {

            query.whereKey("location", nearGeoPoint: PFGeoPoint(latitude: 37.411822, longitude: -121.941125), withinMiles: 10)
            query.limit = 200;
            query.orderByDescending("commentsNo")

        }
    }        
    return query
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!, object: PFObject!) -> PFTableViewCell! {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as TableViewCell
    cell.yakText.text = object.valueForKey("text") as String
    cell.yakText.numberOfLines = 0
    var thumbnail = object["image"] as PFFile
    cell.thumb.file = thumbnail
    cell.thumb.loadInBackground()        
    var dateCreated = object.createdAt as NSDate
    var dateFormat = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormat.dateFormat = "EEE, MMM d, h:mm a"
    cell.time.text = NSString(format: "%@", dateFormat.stringFromDate(dateCreated))
    let replycnt = object.objectForKey("replies") as Int
    let numberOfReplies = comments?.count as Int!
    cell.replies.text = "\(numberOfReplies) Comments"
    return cell
}


override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)           {
    if(segue.identifier == "yakDetail"){
        let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()
        let obj = self.objects[indexPath!.row] as PFObject
        let navVC = segue.destinationViewController as UINavigationController
        let detailVC = navVC.topViewController as DetailViewController
        detailVC.yak = obj
    }
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {


    tableView.reloadData()

  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're letting Parse manage the query, which you seem to be, then you need to call `loadObjects()` to tell parse to run the query and populate the table.

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
  self.loadObjects()
}
```

Internally that is calling `tableView.reloadData()` after it finishes populating `self.objects`. Simply FYI, not something you need to worry about, but handy to know if you want to implement it yourself (which you may want to do later if you want more control over the process).

Answer (score 1):

Try this,if it is useful for you:

Add the following Method above the viewDidLoad-Method

```
func refresh(sender:AnyObject)
{
    // Updating your data here...

    self.tableView.reloadData()
    self.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
}
```